# Whose gotra has to be mismatched for marriage ? - Only father or both father and mother

Tags: brahmins, gotra

As far as I know Gotra of fathers of bride and bridegroom has to mismatched for marriage between a man and woman.(in brahmins)

Whose gotras has to be mismatched for marriage ? - Only father or both father and mother.

Here I am concerned only with brahmin varna.

Comment: Both should be mismatched, atleast in north india. As one doesn't marry their cousins

Comment: In Northern states, originally 7 generations were excluded. Now it has reduced to 2 generations. That is the parents and grandparents from both sides. Like, Nana, Nani, Dada, Dadi, n the parents of the to be groom/bride. Also, if in these 2 generations someone have, "mana hua bhai or behen" then even their gotra is thereafter excluded.  It's damn complex.

Comment: In Dravida Desh (below Vindyas), it's OK to marry your mother's brother's progeny, or father's sister's progeny. while father's brother's progeny, or mother's sister's progeny are not OK. In Aryavart (above Vindhyas) - even this is not allowed. Arjuna-Subhadra is an exception cos they're not blood related (Kunti was adopted) @YOuwillnotknow